# Ubuntu 14.04 Redirect Domain to Port

Tags: redirect, dns, apache2, port, virtualhost

I am trying to direct mydomain.com to a specific port. I have run netstat and I know that my code is listening at 0.0.0.0:3000. I have the following in /etc/apache2/sites-available

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

I was able to get other domains redirected to a subdirectory. When I test using mydomain.com from a browser, I see the default page.